# How to update the user object in Parse?

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, back4app

I use Node.js and back4app.

I would like to update a field in user object. Therefore I have read the [documentation](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#updating-objects) and have tryed the solution of [similare problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525834/parse-com-update-user-cloud-code-giving-error-206-cannot-modify-user). But nothing works for me.

This is the last code, that I have tryed out:

```
    var progressId = 'xyz';
    var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var user = new User();

    user.save().
        then((user) => {
            user.set("progressId", progressId);
            return user.save();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

According to my error code ("bad or missing username") I need the username. It ist known, but how do I have to use it in this code?

And what is the best way updating a user?

#### My solution you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189064/how-to-update-the-user-object-in-back4app).

Comment: Please, check my answer on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189064/how-to-update-the-user-object-in-back4app/58193771#58193771

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update the user object in back4app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189064/how-to-update-the-user-object-in-back4app)